# Regexp: The point is take only numbers in string containing numbers and "-"

Tags: regex

I have a pattern that is not working :

```
[([0-9]),\-]{7,})
```

The point is take only numbers in string containing numbers and "-".

How i can do that?

Comment: You want to capture all the digits or only one set of them?

Comment: I wand to capture the digits in string with "-". For example 123-12-12. This is my string, because they have 7 digits and "-" inside.

Comment: And you want to capture 123 12 and 12. right?

Comment: Chandranshu - absolutely :)

Comment: In which language do you want it?

Comment: This is turning out to be a badly written problem. You didn't provide any sample input/output, didn't tag any language and now giving your bits & pieces information via comments only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this correct regex with `lookahead` and `word boundary`:

```
\b(?=\D*\d){7})[0-9][0-9-]*[0-9]\b
```

Comment: Why will this not capture hyphens as OP requires?

Comment: My string with numbers and - can be at the center of string.

Comment: Ok used word boundary now. @Chandranshu: I believe OP wants to match hyphen also.

Comment: @user1862520: Edited further after your comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is

```
^[\d-]{7,}$
```

which allows for only digits and hyphens. But I suspect you'll find more constraints, as the above allows for 7 hyphens.

If you want at least 7 digits, with optional hyphens in between, use

```
^-*(\d-*){7,}$
```

Comment: Thank you, it is also necessary.